# How to change/set :mnesia folder in elixir?

Tags: erlang, elixir, mnesia

Is there a way to set `mnesia` folder in Elixir?

There is a way to set this folder using 'mnesia-dir' parameter in command line, but it is not a convenient way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways:

1- Add it in your config.exs:

```
config :mnesia,
   dir: 'mydb_#{Mix.env}'
```

2- Use environments:

```
Application.put_env(:mnesia, :dir, '/tmp/wowdb')
```

Comment: Note that this is using charlists, not binaries!! (took me way too long to realize)